# Why can't I run my Flutter app in a browser? Why isn't there a web folder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

(I did a presentation last night and had this question asked. Couldn't find it on SO so I thought I'd ask and answer it myself to help others out).

When running my flutter project, it is demanding an emulator be available but I want it to run in a browser. I noticed that there's an android folder and an ios folder but no web folder. How do I get it to run on the web?

Answer (score -1):

You were on the wrong channel when you created the project. Flutter has multiple channels. To fix it, you'll go to the 'master' channel and add the web components.

Run these commands in your project folder:

```
$ flutter channel master
$ flutter config --enable-web
$ flutter create .
```

Don't worry; it doesn't clobber or remove anything when you `flutter create .`. It just adds the web capability. Now when you run, it'll recognize a browser as a valid environment.

Comment: There's no need of switching to `master` channel `beta` is enough.

By the way, you are answering you own questions?

Comment: Wow @KarolLisiewicz, harsh to downvote it. Yes, I explained that in the question -- It is because the question was not asked on SO that I could see. I put it out there to help folks who might be Googling. That is a standard practice ... in fact when you ask a SO question, answering it yourself is merely a checkbox. #TheMoreYouKnow. :-)

Comment: Almost forgot ... `master` is correct. The problem was that they were on the `stable` channel. As of today, that doesn't work. master does. Thanks for letting us know that `beta` does as well!